# placeholder align issue with android webview

Tags: placeholder

Now in my project, using webview to display html.

For one input field, we want to align the placehoder to right.

```
-webkit-input-placeholder {text-align: right; color: red;}
```

The placeholder is red, but not align right.

This just occurs on Android 4.x, not on the desktop chrome and ios webview.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [Center align placeholder issue in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982290/center-align-placeholder-issue-in-android)

Comment: Also, I did answer it with a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {text-align: right; color: red;}
```