# Center align placeholder issue in android

Tags: android, webview, placeholder

In my android application there is webview to display html.
In webview, for input field, we want placeholder to center align.
Placing style

```
-webkit-input-placeholder {text-align: center;}
```

but placeholder is not aligning center. it's working fine with browser when we test.
Could any one help me on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has a bug here :(, centering just won't work. You can use this polyfill: https://github.com/diy/jquery-placeholder and it supports the "force" attribute. That attribute makes it run even on browser that "support" placeholder, like android.

```
$('#myInput').placeholder({force:true});
```

Then use regular CSS to style the placeholder class provided by the plugin

```
.placeholder{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {text-align: center;}
```

Try this.

Or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        input::-webkit-input-placeholder
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="asdf" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for inconvenience as it was that you suggest. I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: No luck, it's not worked for android, and still showing left aligned on android device.

Comment: @Pankaj bro. i send you one new answer try this.

Comment: And Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381446/center-html-input-text-field-placeholder

Comment: Does anyone have anymore suggestions? I am also encountering the exact same issue. It centers in the browser but not android webview.